# How do you prevent the user from seeking over adverts introduced in HLS using the EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag?

Tags: http-live-streaming

I need to setup HLS streaming to serve files to iOS devices.  After reading the specification posted on ietf.org I am confused on how you make sure adverts are not skipped... so:

How do you prevent the user from seeking over adverts introduced in HLS using the EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag?

It seems easy enough to insert the ad videos, but can't the user just skip them by seeking?

Comment: @vipw: Is that a real response?  Obviously the video player is in charge of this and not the server.  Since when can you control the html5 video tag implementation on an iphone... hence my question?

Comment: You don't have to use an html4 video tag to play HLS. I don't think any browser maker is going to implement a "no-seeking" feature, because it makes the user experience worse. So you'll have to make your own player, or else your own media server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the server side/playlist side, you could introduce a mechanism to not serve the content faster than clock time. Serving the segments would become an active script that performs some sort of clock validation.

The algorithm to disallow seeking past commercials, but still allow seeking within the content would be somewhat difficult to write. If you assume the viewer won't predict when a commercial is coming, then as soon as the first advertisement segment is requested, a countdown could be started. Until the end of the countdown, http requests outside of the commercial break could be made to return an error, or even the advertisement segments. This would probably wreak havoc on the player's seek bar, however.

What might be easier/more reliable is to write your own video player app.

Comment: For one example of this behavior As A Service, Google IMA does this (or it can be done with their SDK), if you search for "Snapback".